# Way to force index for item in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I set up a script where I search through a given directory for pdf files containing "cover", "resume", and "references", insert them into a list, then merge them. The search terms look like this, where the key is the search term and the value is the index where it should be inserted into the list:

```
searchTerms = {"cover": 0,
    "resume":1,
    "references":2}
```

And the initial list looks like this:

```
pdfsToBeMerged = ["placeholder", "placeholder", "placeholder"]
```

After I search through the files and have appended them to this list, I loop through the list and delete all "placeholder" items. These files are then merged.

What I'm wondering if there is a Python function that will somehow automate this "placeholder" step? Like a function that will insert a searchTerm and append it to a blank list at its index and *keep* it there. For example, if a "references" file is found first, it will be appended to index 2 and will *stay* there regardless of if it finds the other files?

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of lists:

```
pdfsToBeMerged = [[], [], []]
```

Then you can `append` to the correct list.

```
for term in searchTerms.keys()
    if term in filetext:
        pdfsToBeMerged[searchTerms[term]].append(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the solution you might want, but maybe it is not that big a problem to include the placeholders.

A somewhat cleaner way to do it would be the following:

```
# Initialize with None instead of "placeholder"
pdfs_to_be_merged = [None] * 3

# Insertion as usual
pdfs_to_be_merged[index] = pdf

# Get the cleaned list
[pdf for pdf in pdfs_to_be_merged if pdf is not None]
```